# How can I create this inverted outer radius in a div?

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to create this pointed arrow for a div which has the following design:

[image]

What I did so far was:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #F6F4FF;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -8px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #F6F4FF;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Is there a way to do it including that border that follows this rounded path?

Comment: use `clip-path` : `clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 98% 100%, 66% 100%, 49% 83%, 33% 100%, 1% 100%);`

Comment: The problem with clip-path is that I can not add the radius border as I said in my question. It's not possible with polygons, as far as I know.

Answer (score -2):

changed in your before

```css
  z-index: 1;
  border-top: lightgray;
  border-left: lightgray;
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #F6F4FF;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -8px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #F6F4FF;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-top: lightgray;
  border-left: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: clip-path with polygons doesn't provide the ability to round corners.